# Empty while loop in Future causes Future to never return in Scala

Tags: scala, while-loop, future, scalatest

My question is probably vague (could not think of how to describe it well) but hopefully this example will make things more clear:

```
class IntTestFake extends FunSpec with ScalaFutures {

  describe("This"){
    it("Fails for some reason"){

      var a = "Chicken"

      val b = "Steak"

      def timeout() = Future{
        while(a != b){}
      }

      Future{
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        a = b
      }

      whenReady(timeout(), Timeout(20 seconds), Interval(50 milliseconds))(result => result)
    }

    it("Passes...why?!?"){
      var a = "Chicken"

      val b = "Steak"

      def timeout() = Future{
        while(a != b){
          println("this works...")
        }
      }

      Future{
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        a = b
      }

      whenReady(timeout(), Timeout(20 seconds), Interval(50 milliseconds))(result => result)
    }
  }
}
```

In the first test (`Fails for some reason`) the while loop has an empty body. In the second test (`Passes...why?!?`) the while loop body has a println statement in it. My original thought was garbage collection was doing something funky but with that `whenReady` statement I am expecting something to return so I would expect GC to leave it alone until then. Apologies if this has already been asked I could not find an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` needs to be `@volatile`, without it writes from other threads are not guaranteed to be visible to the current thread, until it hits a "memory barrier" (a special point in the code, where all caches are flashed - in a *conceptual sense* as pointed out in the comment, not necessarily mapping directly to how exactly hardware off a particular cpu handles that). This is why the second case works - there's plenty of memory barriers inside a `println` call.

So, changing `var a ...` to `@volatile var a ...` will make it work ... but, seriously, don't use `vars`. At least, not until you have learned enough scala to be able to recognize the cases where you have to have them.

Comment: Thank you, I try not to use vars and mostly do not. This was for curiosity not production code - I understand synchronization fairly well and was more curious why the second worked and the first did not. So is it accurate to say that any 'blocking' code would force the thread to reevaluate the variable?

Comment: Not really. The thread will flush it's caches when it hits memory barrier, but the other thread, that is supposed to modify the value may not have committed it's write by then. The proper way is to make the variable volatile (or synchronize access) explicitly  rather than relying on side effects of unrelated code.

Comment: @Dima It is highly unlikely that a modern processor would flush any caches in this situation because that is a really expensive operation. Much more likely that Transactional Memory or specific atomic cache operations would be used.

Comment: @Tim My terminology is not precise, because I don't really know details of hardware implementations. When I say "flush caches" I am speaking in terms of java memory model guarantee, that all writes to memory before memory barrier become visible to any reads that will happen after. I updated the answer to clarify that.

Comment: @Dima The problem is that memory barriers are not used to implement `volatile` values. `volatile` is more about the kinds of optimisations that a compiler can do, such as caching values, re-ordering statements, and optimising loops. A `volatile` value is always read from memory each time it is used and always written to memory each time it is updated, and reads and writes are never re-ordered or optimised away. The processor handles the task of making sure that all threads see a consistent view of memory, so each thread sees the same value for the `volatile` variable (eventually).

Comment: @Tim how is it "the problem"?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the code is reading a `var` from two threads without warning the compiler that it is going to do this, and this leads to unpredictable behaviour. The compiler does not know that the value of `a` is going to change under its feet, so it is perfectly allowed to cache that value in a register or some other bit of memory. If it does, that `while` loop is going to spin forever.

It happens that your first test fails and the second succeeds, but this is a result of the particular compiler and scheduler that you are using, and could be different on a different system.

The solution is to avoid using a shared variable and use a proper synchronisation mechanism. In this case, a `Promise` would probably do the trick.